# Issue with deprecated php function

Tags: php

I have this warning here: `Function split() is deprecated`
I tried replacing it with the explode function. I don't know, maybe I did something wrong, but this is the part of the code apparently deprecated, could you please help me with this?

thanks!

```
$kt = split(' ', $levels);
```

Comment: Reading the manual would have saved asking ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What did you try with [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)?

```
$kt = explode(' ', $levels);
```

Should break it into an array on each space in the string.

Comment: This is strange, i tried it once like this, but maybe i've done any error while writing.. t now works :) thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `explode` instead of this.Split is deprecated now.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php